Issue Setting GDM Login Manager to 125% Fractional Scaling on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, and I'm unable to set the GDM login manager to a fractional scaling of 125%. As far as I know, the scaling-factor option only supports integer values, so setting it to 2 gives 200% scaling, and 1 gives 100%. However, I want the login screen to match my desktop scaling, which is set to 125%. I tried the following method but ended up with 200% scaling:
sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/50_gdm_gsettings_override.gschema.override

[org.gnome.desktop.interface]
scaling-factor=2

sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/

Please suggest a way to set the scaling to 125%.
